# Oracle trigger to update current row based on the data of one of the column

Tags: oracle, function, triggers, oracle11g, xmltype

I have a function called my_func , I would like to pass one of the field of the latest row inserted and update  another field in that same row with the value returned from function.

My DDL is,

```
create table sampletable ( indexid number(19,0) , xmlcolumn xmltype not null , checkfield raw(30) null) xmltype column xmlcolumn store as binary xml;
```

This is my insert query

```
insert into sample_table values ( 1 , some_xml_document  );
```

Following is my trigger, which is incorrect ofcourse

```
create or replace 
trigger compute_func
after insert on sampletable
for each row
declare 
  returned_value raw(30);
begin
 returned_value := my_func(sampleable.xmlcolumn);
 update sampletrigger set checkfield = returned_value; 
end;
```

Answer (score 2):

Don't use `update` just assign the value. Additionally you need to use a `BEFORE` trigger, because you cannot change column values in an `AFTER` trigger.

```
create or replace trigger compute_func
   before insert on sampletable
for each row
begin
 :new.checkfield := my_func(:new.xmlcolumn);
end;
```

More details in the manual: http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e25519/triggers.htm#LNPLS655

Comment: Am getting errors like, Error(2,3): PL/SQL: Statement ignored
Error(2,3): PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.CHECKFIELD' must be declared

Comment: @NishanthLawrence: works for me: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/571f3/1  (Note that the trigger must be changed to an `BEFORE INSERT` trigger - you used an `AFTER INSERT` trigger)

Comment: Am getting the same error when I used before too , by the way in your sqlfiddle you are just modifying the same field. I am trying to set one field based on the value of an xmltype field

Comment: @NishanthLawrence: the error `PLS-00201: identifier 'NEW.CHECKFIELD' must be declared` either means your table does not have a column name `checkfield` or you forgot the colon `:` in front of the `NEW`. It must be `:new.checkfield` not `new.checkfield`. The error has nothing to do with calling a function

Comment: You were right I missed the colon, but I wanted trigger to be executed after the insertion. As I wanted to access the xmlcolumn after insertion